# Customer account nav menu restyling

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I've added some links in my menu in `customer_account.xml`

But items don't go one below the other, they're one next to each other (for my custom links only, default links are ok)

This is my `customer_account.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="customer-account-navigation-contacts">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mycontacts/contacts/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes contacts</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="customer-account-navigation-factures" after="customer-account-navigation-contacts" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mybills/factures/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes factures</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code :

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="first-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/Controller</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">First Link</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="First Link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/controller</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Second Link</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">22</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Nop, same result

Comment: Post screenshot how you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link-one" after="-" >
              <arguments>
                  <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link Label 1</argument>
                  <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your-custom-path</argument>
              </arguments>
       </block>
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link-two" after="-" >
              <arguments>
                  <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link Label 2</argument>
                  <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your-custom-path</argument>
              </arguments>
       </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link-one">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your-custom-path</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Link Label 1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link-two">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your-custom-path</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Link Label 2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```